# textarea sizing in different cf7

Tags: css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have an Issue in targetting the different contact forms of my site.I have tried to fetch the unique contactform id from dev tools.It doesn't work with the textarea field which i am targetting to change its width and border properties.It affects my other contact forms in the other pageshttp://canadaimmigrationconsultant.org/canada-express-entry-system/.

My changes are made to the this link http://canadaimmigrationconsultant.org/contact-us/

```
.wpcf7-f2874-p1465-o1 .wpcf7 input[type=text],
.wpcf7 input[type=email],
.wpcf7 input[type=text],
.wpcf7 input[type=text],
.wpcf7-select {
  font-size:12px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  background:#ffffff;
}
.wpcf7-f2874-p1465-o1 .wpcf7textarea {
  border:1px solid orange;
  background:#ffffff;
  width:220%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have just made a simple mistake out there..

The selector you are using is id..

```
#wpcf7-f2874-p1465-o1 textarea{
height: 100px;
}
```

Please change . from # so that you could choose the unique ID

Comment: Thanks for the response. But the ID selector is not working for the contact form 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can add different IDs to all contact forms. like this `[contact-form-7 id="53" title="Contact form 1" html_id="formID"]`.

And with this form id, you can give CSS to your form `textarea`.